# PHP: on select change, post form to self

Tags: php, javascript, forms, postback

It's basically what the title says.. I have a form with a select control that I want to force the form to post back to self on change.

```
$bmsclientlist = $clientobj->getBMSClientList();

echo '<form name="changebmsid" method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '"><select name="bmsid">';

foreach($bmsclientlist as $bmsclient) {
    $var = '';
    if($client['bmsid'] == $bmsclient['id']) {
        $var = ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo '<option value="' . $bmsclient['id'] .'"'. $var .'>' .$bmsclient['clientname'] . '</option>';
}

echo '</select></form>';

$backupobj = new AdminBackup();

if(isset($_POST['bmsid']){
    $statusarray = $backupobj->getStatusTotalsbyId($_POST['bmsid']);
}else{
    $statusarray = $backupobj->getStatusTotals();
}
```

I know it's going to involve some javascript but I'm not too sure how to achieve this.

Any help most appreciated!

Thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a `<select>` that will submit the parent form

```
<form method="post" action="#" name="myform">
    <select name="x" onchange="myform.submit();">
        <option value="y">y</option>
        <option value="z">z</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

All you have to do is give a name to your `<form>` and add the onchange event to your `<select>`...

---

Adam is right. While the example above works perfectly, I would do it like this:

Using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) but there are many other options available...

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mySelect').change(function(){
            myform.submit();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
```

and the form

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="" name="myform">
    <select name="x" id="mySelect">
        <option value="y">y</option>
        <option value="z">z</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Note that while this is the core way to do it, it's not semantic code - the onchange should be abstracted to the document head or an external script using a dom load event such as jquery `$(document).ready`

Comment: Nice simple example of unobtrusive js.

Comment: In your example, what is the benefit to using jQuery?

@adam, would you be able to edit andre's answer to reflect your suggestions? I'm curious how to make this better.

Comment: @RyanEdwards, Adam's comment was mentioning the first part of my answer. The jQuery part already reflects his suggestions with jQuery placed at the document `<head>`. Benefits of using jQuery? You can accomplish the same with less code.

Comment: this.form.submit(); is easier to reuse.

Answer (score 8):

a quick fix is this:

Add an onchange attribute to your selectlist

```
<select name="bmsid" onchange="javascript: form.submit();">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your select menu to this:

```
<select name="bmsid" onchange="document.forms['changebmsid'].submit()">
```

**Update**

Here's another possible approach:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.forms['myform'].addEventListener('change', function() {
            this.submit();
        }, true);
    };
</script>
```

Put that anywhere on your page, and you can leave you form as it is.