# Printing the selection of a drop down list using php

Tags: php, html

I want to print the selected item value of a drop down list in html by using php.

This is what I was trying to do.
   
    Year 
    Year I Sem I
    Year I Sem II
    Year II Sem I
    Year II Sem II
    Year III Sem I
    Year III Sem II
    Year IV Sem I
    Year IV Sem II

```
    echo $semester ;
```

?>`

Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think more information is needed in order to properly help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
<?php 
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
  echo $_POST['sel'];
}
?>
 <form action="" method="post">
<select name='sel'>
 <option value='Year 1'>Year 1</option>
 <option value='Year 2'>Year 2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: i did the same thing that you have expressed.But it did not give any answer.Actually what I wanted to do is,to print the value according to the changes which I will make to the selection of the drop down list.Your consideration is highly appreciated.

Comment: Then you will have to go with jquery/javascript..follow @rdanusha 's answer

Comment: and if you still for some reason want to do it in php, consider the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976222/php-on-select-change-post-form-to-self

Answer (score -1):

You can use Jquery instead of using PHP.

Code:

```
<html>

  <p id="showoutput">Display Text</p>

  <select name="cmb1" id="cmb1">
     <option value="val1">YOUR TEXT 1<option>
     <option value="val2">YOUR TEXT 2<option>
     <option value="val3">YOUR TEXT 2<option>
  <select>

  <script>
     $('#cmb1').on('change', function() {
       $('#showoutput').html($(this).val());
     });
  </script>
</html>
```